# Java: StringWriter with XML content into Excel file

Tags: java, xml, excel, jaxb, apache-poi

I'm kind of new to Java. I have a java method that produces a StringWriter with XML content by using JAXB:

**PrepareXMLService.java**

```
public StringWriter prepare(Report report) throws JAXBException {
        StringWriter xmlStringWriter = new StringWriter();

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Report.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(report, xmlStringWriter);

        return xmlStringWriter;
    }
```

**XML content of the xmlStringWriter**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<report>
    <reportObject>
        <object>CLIENT_ID</object>
        <objectValue>1111111</objectValue>
    </reportObject>
    <reportContent>
        <reportInterval>
            <startDate>2015-07-01T00:00:00+03:00</startDate>
            <endDate>2016-06-30T23:59:59+03:00</endDate>
        </reportInterval>
        <client>
            <clientId>1111111</clientId>
            <clientName>test</clientName>
            <clientTown>test</clientTown>
            <clientAddress>test</clientAddress>
        </client>
        <transaction>
            <transactionDate>2015-10-23T00:00:00+03:00</transactionDate>
            <transactionAmount>23</transactionAmount>
            <transactionCurrency>7777</transactionCurrency>
            <transactionClientId>8798768789</transactionClientId>
            <transactionNetAmount>22</transactionNetAmount>
        </transaction>
    </reportContent>
</report>
```

I need to create an Excel file out of this StringWriter. I have to use Apache POI for it, but I don't really understand how I can do it by using my StringWriter. I cannot write a physical XML file with data in order to read it after, because that is forbidden by the business side and I don't think that is quite efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solution given in the below link 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076189/enterprise-java/book-excerpt--converting-xml-to-spreadsheet--and-vice-versa.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a very nice article. It uses the DocumentBuilderFactory. I wanted to avoid using that, but it seems that this is the way to go.